# How to "pre-authenticate" another user with Windows Azure Access Control?

Tags: azure, oauth, wif, acs, azure-acs

I'm trying to use Windows Azure Access Control to avoid the security risks in using usernames/passwords in my app and to simplify the authentication. However, this is a site that can be used by medium or large companies that may wish to "pre-authenticate" users. In other words, they may want to bulk create users by putting in the users' Windows Live IDs and create their accounts automatically, before that user has ever signed in through Azure ACS. I could accomplish this by sending that user an email with a link to a one-time-use page to create their account, but I am hoping to do something a little more seamless.

What I'm trying to do is equivalent to how Team Foundation Service (*.visualstudio.com) lets you add users to a team project just by putting in their Windows Live IDs and once you do, they can log in and access the project, even if that user had never signed in to TFS previously.

What I don't understand is how to do that using ACS and System.IdentityModel. I can use the nameidentifier claim to uniquely identify a user, but how do I get a nameidentifier for another user through a given provider?

I'm sorry if I'm not explaining this well, so feel free to ask questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really an answer but just wanted to share my thoughts on the issue.

The problem with ACS and Windows Live authentication is that ACS never returns the user's email address. All we get back from ACS is a token telling me that the user is authenticated. This token is created based on your ACS realm (i.e. if you change the ACS realm, a new token will be created by ACS for the same user). Again, the admins of the company who are using your application can enter the email addresses of the user but there's no way to get that email address back from ACS.

Just thinking out loud :), there're a few things you could do:

1. You use ACS for authenticating the user and then use Windows Live REST API to get more details about the user using the token sent by ACS. By using Windows Live REST API, you can get more details like name, email address etc. about a user. Or you could use just Windows Live API for authenticating the user. I'm not 100% sure but I think this is what Team Foundation Service does. Do take a look at http://zud.io as it does the same i.e. uses Windows Live API.
2. Another idea would be to create some sort of invitation tokens. In this approach, admins would "invite" folks. They would create invitation record by providing the name, email address of the users and the application would create unique invitation tokens. The application could then create an invitation link using which users would come to your application and authenticate themselves. Once authentication is done, you could look up the invitation record and retrieve user information from the database and create user record and associate the authentication token with the user record. The issue with this approach is that a user may not use the same Live Id as provided by the administrator. For example, I have at least 3 live ids and if I have that invitation link, I could sign with any of those live ids and the application won't be able to stop me from registering.
3. Yet another idea would be to use Windows Azure Active Directory (WAAD) instead of ACS. You could consume Graph API in your application to create new users for your clients. You're still not managing user names and passwords as that is done by WAAD. The two issues I could think of there are - a) As an end user, I have to remember one more username/password combination and b) At the time of login, I have to provide my credentials in `myusername@yourtenantname.onmicrosoft.com` which to me personally is a big hassle.

We too have been going through the same pain and for now we have decided to go with approach #2.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you! That's exactly the information I was looking for. I think approach #2 is going to be the best bet it seems. I just wanted confirmation from someone else that it wasn't possible to "query" ACS for another user's nameidentifier for my realm. If anyone knows that this is possible, that would certainly solve the problem, but I don't see any APIs that are capable of that. Thanks for the help!